# Averaging multiple masked numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a problem that puzzles me a lot the last days. I want to average different masked arrays but it seems I cannot because my mapped arrays do not have the same map pattern.

For example. I have three arrays:

```
 [ --  --  --]
 [ 1.  2.  --]
 [ 2.  3.  --]
 [ --  --  --]

 [ --  2.  2.]
 [ --  2.  3.]
 [ --  --  --]
 [ --  --  --]

 [ 2   1.  --]
 [ 1   1.  --]
 [ --  --  --]
 [ --  --  --]
```

I want the result to be the average of these arrays, but the averaging of a masked element with a valid element should not take account the masked elements. That means in the (0,0) position I have two masked elements and 1 valid ( value =2 ), so the final result should calculate only the average of the valid elements.

```
 [ 2   1.5  2]
 [ 1   2    3]
 [ 2   --  --]
 [ --  --  --]
```

I have 28 arrays like them that I want to combine and so far I have to do complicated loops and actions to achieve the expected results. Is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: [`a.mean(axis=0)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.mean.html#numpy.ma.mean) doesn't work?

Comment: All the arrays have the same size. Sorry It was in error in array one.

Comment: @Evert No it does not work, when I am trying for example:

(array1+array2+array3).mean(axis=0)

then I get only a mean for the elements that are valid in EVERY array.

Comment: Of course it does work; you just have to take the intermediate step, like Saullo explains below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform them into a 3-D masked array and then take the average along `axis=0`, for example:

```
np.ma.array((a, b, c)).mean(axis=0)
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ma.array([[99, 99, 99],
                 [ 1.,  2., 99],
                 [ 2.,  3., 99],
                 [99, 99, 99]],
                 mask=[[True, True, True],
                       [False, False, True],
                       [False, False, True],
                       [True, True, True]])
b = np.ma.array([[99,  2.,  2.],
                 [99,  2.,  3.],
                 [99, 99, 99],
                 [99, 99, 99]],
                 mask=[[True, False, False],
                       [True, False, False],
                       [True, True, True],
                       [True, True, True]])
c = np.ma.array([[2., 1., 99],
                 [1., 1., 99],
                 [99, 99, 99],
                 [99, 99, 99]],
                 mask=[[False, False, True],
                       [False, False, True],
                       [True, True, True],
                       [True, True, True]])
```

and:

```
np.ma.array((a, b, c)).mean(axis=0)

masked_array(data =
 [[2.0 1.5 2.0]
 [1.0 1.6666666666666667 3.0]
 [2.0 3.0 --]
 [-- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False  True]
 [ True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: Thanks Saullo! That works exactly as I would like :)